# Add user to a group after the user makes a comment in that group

Tags: rules, organic-groups, 7

is this possible in Drupal Commons (Drupal 7) using Rules:

If a user makes a comment on a post in a certain group, have a rule which makes the user a member of the group automatically.

Why do I want to do this? Well, the contributors block in Drupal Commons is not showing all those who comment in a group. I found that the reason for this was that the particular user is not yet listed as an active member of the group.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ... yes, it is possible ... and easy to do ... with Rules.

If anyone coming across this is new to Rules or needs a refresher I highly recommend Johan Falk's free screencast series. It's excellent. http://nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework

[See the screenshot for how I did it](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx2Q3IBQpRK7Y3ZJc09DYXJhTXc/edit?usp=sharing), and also the exported Rule below.

```
{ "rules_lambeth_comment_join_group" : {
"LABEL" : "lambeth comment join group",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "og", "comment" ],
"ON" : [ "comment_insert" ],
"IF" : [
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "comment:node" ], "field" : "og_group_ref" } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "og_subcribe_user" : {
      "user" : [ "comment:author" ],
      "group" : [ "comment:node:og-group-ref:0" ]
    }
  }
]
}
}
```